# Can Kafka Streams be used instead of Producer?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Kafka Streams with RocksDB store looks very fine for processing existed messages but can it be used as fault tolerance producer?

Idea to create custom Processor that will check new events in some in-memory  generate every 10-100ms and forward it to ProcessorContext with attached store looks really crazy. Is there any straightforward approach?

Comment: You cannot do that. Not sure thought, what you try to achieve?

Comment: Unclear what you're trying to achieve, so I can only assume that you want to make Kafka Streams fault-tolerant. There is no need in doing that, fault tolerance is part of Streams design. RocksDB indeed keeps some data, but this all can be restored from source and internal Kafka topics, even if you go kill RocksDB. Kafka Streams is just an abstraction over consumers and producers.

Comment: I want to have fault tolerant producer without implementing saving to local backup store in case of kafka fail. Then I should read from backup store by schedule and try to send data to kafka again and again. It is very boring.

From other side kafka stream has this capability out of the box but the source topic  needed.

Comment: What you describe is not how Kafka Streams works or what it's designed for. If you want to have a producer with local state, you need to use a `KafakProducer` and some local store.